# YARD: Document non-useful or unintentional return

Tags: ruby, documentation, yard

I have an impure function like so:

```
# Impure function: Sets the status for a report_schedule, uses last_sent to
# calculate status
# @param report_schedule [Hash]
# @return [String] Non-useful: value of last_sent that was set
def self.set_report_schedule_status(report_schedule)
  # Some logic that calculates status of report_schedule
  report_schedule['status'] = status
  report_schedule['last_sent'] = Time.now.to_s
end
```

What I want this function to do is set `status` and `last_sent`, but the side effect here is that it returns `Time.now.to_s`. Is there a proper way to document this?
Alternatively is my function definition wrong or should I just end with a `return nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Should be just adding    `return nil`

Ruby automatically appends return to the last thing executed in a method